# Need to move child onto their own Apple ID

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My child has been sharing my Apple ID for years in order to buy music for her iPod (now iPhone and iPad). For years, we had our separate devices and PCs where our music libraries resided. However, recently, I activated iCloud for my new iPhone and iPad and now all of our data has meshed. I have her contacts, she has my contacts, music, etc. My question is how can I set up a distinct Apple ID for her but not have her lose her contacts, music, settings, etc.?

Comment: Three big areas here. 1) Contacts and Calendars - you can export them and move them easily to a new account using a computer for a one time move. 2) Settings, etc. can move similarly from a backup through iTunes (or even iCloud) 3) You won't be able to split the apps. You can either rename /relinquish that account to her or have her start with a new account.

Comment: Also should look into family sharing

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a new AppleID account you will not have access to items bought from the iTunes store. But iCloud accounts are separate from AppleID accounts; she can have a unique iCloud account with her own contacts, email, and other settings, but will need to use the shared AppleID to have access to the apps, music, books, movies, etc... bought from iTunes.

There are some ugly hackish ways to get around this, but they sound like a waste of time and very sketchy to me.

Comment: Thanks guys.  She currently bought/added 99% of the apps and and maybe 75% of the music so it's easier if she holds onto the Apple ID.  My concern is for the other 25% of songs I bought and are unique in my library.  What you're saying is if I create a new ID on my PC the songs in my library will NOT be available to my devices (where they currently reside?) I just want to keep my music I bought - I can start fresh more easily than her.

Comment: iTunes allows you to authorize up to 5 computers, and that should enable you to share the music library (or whatever songs you would like). Even though I've used this feature a lot, and it has worked very well, I'm not completely familiar with it, and can't give you a more step-by-step approach.

Comment: SAJ, you may be able to burn audio CDs of those songs then re-rip them into your new iTunes.

Comment: See the "Using one Apple ID for iCloud and a different Apple ID for Store Purchases" section of [Apple's KB article #HT4895](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895) for how to set up the split config Dave recommends.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too much music (you were talking about 25%), you could search for a tool called iRip. Put your music on an iPod /iPhone, plug it into your pc and use iRip on it. I think they have a trial version for free that should do the work for this one session.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer, Tom! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, but I don't want people think that I'm advertising it you know? ;)

http://thelittleappfactory.com/irip/

Comment: Are you? There's no problem with advertising it. You are [allowed to promote your own software](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) providing you disclose that you are affiliated with it.

Comment: No, it's not my own software. But thanks for telling me ;-)

Comment: Oh, okay. From the way you said it, it sounded like you didn't want to promote it since you were a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a backup and an iCloud removal to transfer all the contacts from the cloud to local contacts.

1. Open iCloud settings and turn off each bin of data, one by one. For each choose to delete things you don't want transferring to your child and and keep on the phone the things you want them to have.
2. Make a full backup of the phone (perhaps two - one to iTunes and another to iCloud after turning that one item on again).
3. Erase all content and settings on the phone and sign the child up for a free Apple ID as part of the new user enrollment (look up Apple's KB article  - the steps to do that are very picky, you have to say no to a lot of prompts and then set up an account as part of a "free purchase").
4. Once the child has their AppleID, erase the device again and restore from the backup. Clean out any contacts that don't belong to the child (same for calendars).
5. Only then sign in to iCloud on that device and put the child's contacts in to their cloud account.